# CSS grid inside a grid

Tags: css, grid, 960.gs

I am using a 960 Grid System, I am trying to achieve something like the following  --

```
|-----| |-------------------|
|     | |  |--|  |-----|    |
|     | |  |  |  |     |    |
|     | |  |--|  |-----|    |
|     | |                   | 
|     | |  |------|  |--|   |
|     | |  |      |  |  |   |
|     | |  |------|  |--|   |
|-----| |-------------------|
```

Is there a way of doing so? The only reason I need the second set of divs in my right column is because the left column is quite long and I dont want the space between the 2nd set of columns.

I would really appreciate any guidance if there is a better way of achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This capability is built into the Grid 960 system.  You just give the left and right nested grid items the classes "alpha" and "omega", respectively.

Here's an example:

```
<div class="container_12">

  <div class="grid_3">
  </div>

  <div class="grid_9">

    <div class="grid_4 alpha">
    </div>

    <div class="grid_5 omega">
    </div>

    <div class="grid_5 alpha">
    </div>

    <div class="grid_4 omega">
    </div>

  </div>

</div><!-- end .container_12 -->
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, -- That will help me get the first row of 2 divs in the 9 column grid. However the 2nd Row of divs still wouldn't get styled.

Comment: Just add the appropriate grid classes to the second row divs as well. My updated code would give you two rows of nested divs.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're willing to consider other frameworks, here's how you achieve the desired result with [**Cascade Framework**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/) :

```
<div class="site-center"> <!-- Center all content in a responsive container -->
    <div class="col width-1of4"> <!-- Your left column goes here -->

    </div>
    <div class="col width-fill"> <!-- Your main content goes here -->
        <div class="col"> <!-- First row -->
            <div class="col width-1of3"> <!-- First element of first row -->

            </div>
            <div class="col width-fill"> <!-- Second element of first row -->

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col"> <!-- Second row -->
            <div class="col width-2of3"> <!-- First element of second row -->

            </div>
            <div class="col width-fill"> <!-- Second element of second row -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A grid element in Cascade framework is either

- One of the following HTML elements : section, main, article, header, footer, aside or nav (these elements are polyfilled with the HTMLshiv for old IE in case you need it).
- A div element with a 'col' class (can be used in old IE without a polyfill).

To add a width to a grid element, you add a class of the format 'width-XofY', where Y can be 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16 or 24 and X can be any value lower than X.

More concretely, here are some examples of valid classes you can use in Cascade Framework : 'width-1of2' (width : 50%), 'width-3of4' (width : 25%), 'width-2of5' (width : 40%), 'width-2of5' (width : 40%), 'width-2of7' (width:28.5714286%) and 'width-13of16' (width:81.25%)

Additional to these classes, you can also use the classes 'width-fit' and 'width-fill' that respectively fit to content and fill whatever remains of your 100% width. Or, you could just define your own classes and IDs and just add a custom width for those classes to do things the 'semantic' way.

If your builds include the responsiveness module (which is the case for the recommended builds), the width of all grid elements automatic resets to 100% on mobile. You can use classes like 'mobile-width-3of16', 'phone-width-3of7' or 'tablet-width-2of4' to customize the layout for different width ranges and the classes 'desktop-hidden', 'mobile-hidden', 'phone-hidden' or 'tablet-hidden' to hide content for a specific screen with range.